# How do I fix a spot on my wood desk?

Tags: wood

Some wood seal got removed on my desk. There is a noticible spot. Is there anyway to fix it without refinishing the whole thing?

Comment: Many tricks exist for hiding spots..  They will depend on the original finish and your tolerance for some degree of noticeability.  It would also be helpful to know what the solvent was that removed the finish.

Comment: Natural-grain wood? Vinyl-laminated particle board? Light color? Dark color? Desk's approximate age? Any idea which wood it's made of, or what its natural (unstained) color is?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tinted shellac: adding a metalic dye to a dewaxed shellac: Advantage, can be done in layers, fast drying.  Finish can be blended and buffed.  Once blended, an appropriate top coat to protect all.
2. Stain or dye directly to the 'noticeable spot'.  Over-finish with spray can of clear coat : Lacquer, shellac or polyurethane as appropriate.
3. Stain markers (like a kids paint marker) are available in a multitude of wood tones.  They can be blended on surface and removed with paint thinner as needed.  They should be fixed with an over-finish as in step 2.